# typeahead and playframework alert displays the data but the suggestion comes as undefined

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap, playframework, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I am trying to use Typeahead with Bootstrap 3 for the auto-complete functionality on a search box.

When i make a Ajax call to the server i get the response back as Json. and when i pass that response to process of typeahead i get the suggestions as undefined. but if i print it console or alert i see the data returned from server.

Below is the code

javascript code

```
$('#search-box .typeahead').typeahead({

  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  source: function (query, process) {
      return $.ajax({
            url: "/type_assist/" + query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
                return typeof data == 'undefined' ? false : process(data);
            }
        }); 
  }

});
```

and the java code which processes the url in java script. I am using import play.libs.Json;

```
SortedSet<String> set =  CityZipTypeAssist(charInput);      
        return ok(Json.toJson(set));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this.. it was some changes in the javascript had to add the response into an array object and then pass it to the process below is the code

```
    displayKey: 'value',
  source: function (query, process) {
      return $.ajax({
            url: "/type_assist/" + query,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: false,

            success: function (data) {
                var suggestions = [];
                  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                      var obj = {};
                      obj.label = val;

                      suggestions.push({ value: val });
              });
                  return typeof data == 'undefined' ? false : process(suggestions);
            }
        }); 
  }

});
```